# Is my proof for the statement, "Prove that a continuous function on a closed, bounded interval is bounded", correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

There are 2 parts to this question:

Let $f$ be continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$. Then $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$.

Assume for contradiction that $f$ is unbounded. For any $M \in \mathbb{N} > 0$, there exists $c$ in $[a, b]$ such that $|f(c)| > M$.

Since $[a, b]$ is closed, there exists a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $[a, b]$ that tends to $c$

**Part A:** (Have I really used closedness here? As any point in any set has a sequence which converges to it, for example take the constant sequence. I have adapted this from a statement that A set $A$ is closed if and only if $x \in A$ whenever $x_k \in A$ and $\lVert x_k - x \rVert \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.)

By sequential continuity, $f(x_k)$ must tend to $f(c)$.

Now, aiming for a contradiction:
$ |f(x_k) - f(c)| \geq |f(x_k)| - |f(c)| > |f(x_k)| - M $

Then taking the limit as $k$ tends to infinity.

$ \epsilon > |f(c)| - M > 0$, which does not quite get the contradiction.

**Part B:** Is there a way to finish this proof this way, without using sequential compactness as I have seen in other proofs online?

Comment: Assume $f$ is unbounded and choose $f(x_n)\to\infty$. But then $x_{n_k}\to x$ and $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$, contradicting that $f(x_n)\to\infty$

Comment: Your proof doesn't seem right. There is nothing contradictory in the assertion: $f$ is continuous and $|f(c)|>M$ for some $c$ and $M$. You need to use the fact we can make $M$ arbitrarily large, which leads to the notion of not a sequence converging to $c$ but rather a sequence of $c$s whose values converge to $\infty$, as in Andrew's comment

Comment: I think you are about halfway there. I've typically seen sequential compactness combined with an ansatz function, e.g. 1/|f(x_n)-M|. Then properties of the ansatz are used to demonstrate a contradiction of interval boundedness or closed ness.

Comment: Please do not edit your question after getting an answer.  This creates a moving goalpost for answerers, and can invalidate existing answers.  If you have a new question, use the "Ask Question" button to ask that new question.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advice. I have made another attempt but wanted some clarification:

Assuming $f$ unbounded, this means for all $M$ in the natural numbers there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $[0,1]$ such that 
\[ |f(x_n)| > M. \] (Is this the appropriate phrasing for this step?)

Comment: Since we know this is true for any $M$, we can pick each $x_n$ such that $|f(x_n)| > n$ where $n$ is the index. This means $|f(x_n)|$ tends to infinity. (If I remove the absolute value, then I would have to repeat the process twice for $f(x_n)$ being bounded above and below).

Since $x_n$ is a sequence in a compact space, it has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converging to $x^*$. By sequential continuity, for any $\epsilon$, we can find an $N$ in natural numbers such that $|f(x_{n_k}) - f(x^*)| < \epsilon$ for any $k$ greater than $N$.

Comment: Tip: your hypothesis is: closed and bounded $I$ $\implies$ continuous $f(I)$ is bounded. The anti-hypothesis is: closed and bounded $I$ $\implies$ continuous $f(I)$ is unbounded. If you prove that the anti-hypothesis is not true, then the hypothesis is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: You do not need the sequential continuity, but what do you know about continuous functions on convergent sequences?

Comment: I am not too sure, I cannot see another way of introducing continuity here without the idea of limits i.e. seq. continuity to finish the proof I have provided in the comments @mavavilj

Comment: $\epsilon > |f(x_{n_k}) - f(x^*)| \geq |f(x_{n_k})| - |f(x^*)| > |n_k| - |f(x^*)| \geq |k| - |f(x^*)|.$

So, $\epsilon > |k| - |f(x^*)|$.
(Not sure where to continue from here...)
@Andrew

Comment: The point is that $f(x_n)\to \infty$ means that every subsequence also goes to $\infty$. But there is also a subsequence $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)<\infty$ which is a contradiction

Comment: @palt34 Just consider continuity the normal way (epsilon-delta). Continuity of $f$ means that it can be made arbitrarily close to any other point. What if $f(c)=\infty$ for some $c$ in the domain? Can you have a point arbitrarily close to $\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part A:** No, you haven't really used closedness. You're correct that any point has the constant sequence converging to it. The key in the definition of closedness you've provided is that *$x$ doesn't need to belong to $A$ in the first place*: if you're given a point $x$, then having a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ with $\{x_n\}_n \subseteq A$ *allows you to conclude* that $x \in A$. In any case, closedness isn't enough for this proof - the interval needs to be closed *and bounded*.

**Part B:** I don't believe there's any way to salvage your proof. The problem is that you've just taken *one* arbitrary value of $M$. This doesn't use unboundedness - you're just taking a (possibly large) value of $f$. You really need to use the fact that you have a *sequence* of points $(c_n)_n$ such that $f(c_n) \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: My new attempt:
Assuming $f$ unbounded, there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $[0,1]$ such that $|f(x_n)| > n$ where $n$ is the index, so $|f(x_n)|$ tends to infinity. $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converging to $x^*$. By sequential continuity, for any $\epsilon$, we have $|f(x_{n_k})-f(x^*)|<\epsilon$ for any $k$ greater than $N$.

$\epsilon > |f(x_{n_k}) - f(x^*)| \geq |f(x_{n_k})| - |f(x^*)| > |n_k| - |f(x^*)| \geq |k| - |f(x^*)|.$

So, $\epsilon > |k| - |f(x^*)|.$
(Not sure where to continue from here...) @Sambo

Comment: Take a particular epsilon, say $\epsilon =1$. Then $1+|f(x^*)|>k$, but $k$ can be arbitrarily large. That's your contradiction.

Comment: Note that you still use sequential compactness in your proof.